# Find the length of an array in Chapel

Tags: chapel

I deal with multiple languages, so I'm always hunting for how to do

```
var x = [1,2,3,4];
len(x);     // No, python
x.size;     // No, javascript?
x.size();   // Still no, uh Java?
x.length(); // Grrr
size(x);    // Think that one is C, right?
```

Which one is it? And how does it change for arrays again?  The [array page](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/primers/arrays.html) could use an example.

Comment: > The array page could use an example - Agreed. That might be worth a small issue or pull request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is *javascript*:

```
var x = [1,2,3,4];
writeln(x.size);
```

For completeness, here is a summary of the built-in types with `size`-like fields:

- `range.size`
- `domain.size`
- [`array.size`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/builtins/internal/ChapelArray.html#ChapelArray.size)
- [`tuple.size`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/builtins/internal/ChapelTuple.html)
- [`string.length`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/builtins/internal/String.html#String.string.length)

  - (`string.size` works as of Chapel 1.17 too)

Comment: `range.length` works too, but I personally frown upon that